# This Riley is out of order

Tags: riddle, word, rebus, literature

> My prefix is big in the Middle,
>   my infix is found at the end,
>   my suffix was once at the front,
>   my whole is what is involved.

Hint 1: My two anagrams, as a rebus

> P|S|E A|p|r|i|l 1|5

Hint 2: An alternative fix, which doesn't use the literature tag

> My prefix is one of the middle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the word being clued here is:

> **ENTAILED**

*My prefix is big in the Middle,*

> An **ENT** is a *big* tree-like creature in JRR Tolkien's *Lord of the Rings*, which is set in *Middle* Earth.

*my infix is found at the end,*

> A **TAIL** is *found at the end* of an animal, vehicle or other object.

*my suffix was once at the front,*

> Something which **LED** was *once at the front* (e.g. of a race, a team, a tribe, etc.).

*my whole is what is involved.*

> The word **ENTAILED** is a synonym for *involved*.

As for the hints:

> 1. The word 'ENTAILED' has two anagrams: **DATELINE** and **LINEATED**, which are represented here using the day's date with lines added...
>
>  2. An alternative prefix could be **EN**, *one of the middle* letters of the English alphabet (which is centred around M and N).